# Golang how to scanf after using bufio.NewScanner to scan a single line

Tags: go

So i just want to clarify what is happening in this small piece of code in GOlang. Basically a new scanner is created and it will scan a line and print it via bufio.NewScanner(). After I've scanned and printed the line, i try to scan the next line using scanf to print the decimal but get 0 instead of 2?

Im created a text file with two lines called text.txt which contains:

[text file 'hello\n2'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7KAb.png)

and when i run the program ./main < text.txt

the output is

Hello
0

this is the code

```js
package main
  
import (
  "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
)
  
func main() {
  
    var text string
    var a int

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Scan() 
    text = scanner.Text()
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", text)
    
    fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &a);
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", a);
    
  
}
```

Why is the scanf function not scanning the 2?

Comment: The scanner reads the entire file to its internal buffer. fmt.Scanf fails because the file is at EOF.

Comment: Either read from the scanner or read from `os.Stdin`, but don't try to use both.

Comment: You simply cannot do what you try to do as this is not how bufio.Scanner is able to work.

Answer (score 1):

A bufio scanner stops at the next token (see https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Scan).
Another Scan() is required after `\n`.
Scanner result is text or bytes. A conversion to `int` is required to use the a variable defined. For instance:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
scanner.Scan()
text = scanner.Text()
fmt.Printf("%s\n", text) // should print hello
scanner.Scan()
a, _ = strconv.Atoi(string(scanner.Bytes()[0])) // convert to int
fmt.Printf("printf: %d\n", a); // should print 2
```